# Horizontal asymptotes in a proper subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

If we have a function like $f(x)=x.tan(x)$ with domain $(-\cfrac{\pi}{2},\cfrac{\pi}{2})$, can we say that it does not have any horizontal asymptotes since we can not take the limit as $x$ goes to infinity, ie. $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}x.tan(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's somehow true in my opinion. It depends on the definition of horizontal asymptotes. 
For example we can define the horizontal asymptote to be the value of the limit at the edge of the domain of definition.

Take for example $f(x) = 1/\exp(\frac{1}{1-x^2})$ on the domain $]-1;1[$. Then we can define it to have horizontal asymptote 
$$
\lim_{x\to \pm 1} f(x) = 0
$$

Plot here : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+1%2FE%5E(1%2F(1-x%5E2))+for+x+%3D-1+to+1

Comment: Appelle hendek !